# Will my local file be deleted once I delete it from my storage at dropbox.com?

Tags: dropbox

If I delete a file from my storage at [dropbox.com](http://www.dropbox.com), but it still exists locally on my computer, will syncing cause the local file to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's easily tested: after a few seconds any file deleted through the website will also be deleted from your computer's Dropbox folder.

On a Mac, it will also *not* be moved to your Trash, but really be gone. Of course, it can still be recovered using the Dropbox website though.

Comment: But if I want to start some directory from scratch? The only idea that comes to mind is to delete this folder from the online storage and then sync.

Comment: Please next time make sure your question is complete before asking it; please see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) That said, I don't understand what you mean, but I'm sure it is very easily tested?